# Select all element values from DOM with div class checked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, document

How to get all label values under class "multiselect-dropdown-list" that have div class="checked" (some elements doesn't have class="checked" and I don't need to select them)

[image]

Comment: Please don't include image of code, but link the code itself

Comment: `.multiselect-dropdown-list > .checked > label`

Comment: got to love when there is a checkbox and it uses a class on a div to say it is checked and not the actual checkbox...

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask].  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor. I assume you use some kind of select2 or other plugin that generates code to check hidden chekboxes?

Answer (score 1):

You can select the elements by using jQuery function **.each()**

This is an example :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".multiselect-dropdown-list .checked label").each(function(){
        console.log($(this).text());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="multiselect-dropdown-list">
    <div class="checked">
        <input type="checkbox">
        <label>value 1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checked">
        <input type="checkbox">
        <label>value 2</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox">
        <label>value 3</label>
    </div>
</div>
```